# dd command PERMISSION DENIED Python

Tags: python, root, permission-denied, dd

I have used a command line to run a dd command in Python, however, whenever I try to actually run the command, I get:

dd: opening '/dev/sdb': Permission denied

I know I have to do some kind of root thing? And I only need a certain section of my code to run the dd command, so I don't need to 'root' the whole thing; but the whole 'root' concept confuses me...

Help would be HIGHLY appreciated!!

Comment: Try running the command with `sudo` in front of it, then entering your password when prompted

Comment: Is there a way to run the command with sudo but not be prompted for the password? Basically, is there a way for me to run sudo and supply the command both IN my code, so I don't have to do it once prompted? @DavidRobinson

Comment: For one thing, you could use sudo when you run the Python script, like `sudo python myscript.py`

Comment: And you could use `subprocess` to run the command.

Comment: ...you want to put a password that grants root access into a Python script? What if someone happens to read that?

Comment: I figured it out, @DavidRobinson your advice helped the most, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I have to do some kind of root thing?

Indeed you do!

If you are using linux, `sudo` is the idiomatic way to escalate your user's privilege.

So instead invoke '`sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null`' (for example).  If your script must be noninteractive, consider adding something like `admin    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` to your `sudoers`, or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python, but where do I put the admin ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL? 

I understand to put sudo with my dd code, but I have no clue as to where the other code belongs!

Comment: The other stuff is configuration for your system's `sudoers` file.  [`visudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo) is the typical way to edit this file.

Comment: Yeah, I might have to have someone physically help me at my computer, I don't understand anything you just said. I just started coding a week ago and am still learning. But thanks for trying!

Comment: Well, it's only relevant if it needs to be noninteractive.

Comment: So do I run visudo right before my dd command to add the ALL = NOPASSWD stuff?

Comment: No, you would run it once and only once on every system where you want to run `sudo` without being prompted for a password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33380/discussion-between-brian-cain-and-ohhiloveyouu)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem at the operating system level by changing access rights to the disk. This may be superior to using sudo every time you run your script because you don't have to muck around with passwords or worry that your script goes crazy and wipes out your system.

Sorry if I'm being a bit basic here, but linux uses file permissions to decide how users can access files in the file system. On my machine:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Jun 27 15:04 /dev/sda2
```

The device is owned by 'root' (the super user) and is in the 'disk' group. root and anybody in the disk group can access the device. But 'others' (everybody else) is blocked.

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/null bs=1
dd: opening `/dev/sda2': Permission denied
```

I'm not root and i'm not in the disk group, so the dd fails. I could add myself to the 'disk' group, but that's granting a lot of rights and runs the risk that evil will happen.

What we've seen so far are standard *nix rights, but most modern linux file systems support extended rights. I can give myself rights to read the device

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:td:r /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for td:
```

Now, if I list the device I see a plus sign on the rights string meaning there are extended acls that I can also view

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda2
brw-rw----+ 1 root disk 8, 2 Jun 27 15:04 /dev/sda2

$ getfacl /dev/sda2
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/sda2
# owner: root
# group: disk
user::rw-
user:td:r--
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

And dd works!

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/null bs=1
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.0146606 s, 69.8 kB/s
```

Notice that this is far safer (script can read /dev/sda2) than sudo (script can do everything). I could let other people I don't trust very much use this script by giving them rights to the block device without giving them the keys to the kingdom.

Comment: +1 - Much safer than running as root. Also, granting read-only access is highly desirable when using `dd` with raw block devices, in case you accidentally manage to run something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 ...`

Comment: @Aya yeah, I was practising with my system partition - it could have gone very badly with sudo.